# Unknown haskell operator; `<>`

Tags: haskell, interpolation, monads, string-interpolation

This code appears to use `<>` as an interpolation operator. 
https://github.com/hlian/linklater/blob/master/examples/app/JointPhotographicExpertsGroupTonga.hs

I can not find the documentation nor source for this operator. Any ideas what it does/where its from.

Comment: It's from [Data.Monoid](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html)

Comment: Implicit import is horrible. It's a pity that haskell admits that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traditionally, `<>` is primarily a function defined in `Data.Monoid`.

```
(<>) :: Monoid a => a -> a -> a
(<>) = mappend
```

However, the `semigroups` package has long used it as a method of the `Semigroup` class in `Data.Semigroup`. As of GHC 8, `Data.Semigroup` has moved into the `base` package. There is currently a plan in place for making `Semigroup` a superclass of `Monoid`. Once this is complete, the `<>` function will be entirely replaced by the `<>` method.

Answer (score 2):

Use [hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=%3C%3E) to do a search for definitions in Hackage packages.

In this case it appears that it is the `mappend` operator defined in `Data.Monoid`.

Comment: While I understand that mappend is more flexible than ++, wouldn't ++ have been completely sufficient in this case?

Comment: It allows for easy transitioning between using Strings and using Text - you won't have to go through and change `++` to `Text.append`

Comment: Yes, it would have been sufficient.